# Bootstrap table Media queries

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple Bootstrap Table, and I am trying to wright a media queries using Hidden Columns technique to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` last two `<tr class="none">...</tr>`.

Mine Table:

```
<div id="table">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                      <table class="table table-condensed" width="647">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>Membership Plan</th>
                                  <th>Table heading</th>
                                  <th>Table heading</th>
                                  <th>Table heading</th>
                                  <th>Table heading</th>
                                  <th>Table heading</th>
                                  <th>Table heading</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>Membership Plan</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>Membership Plan</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>Membership Plan</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>Membership Plan</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="none">
                                  <td>Membership Plan</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="none">
                                  <td>Membership Plan</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                                  <td>Table cell</td>
                              </tr>

                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>

          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
```

Media queries:

```
Media Query Section ================================*/

/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    table.table tr.none {
        display: none;
    }

}

/*====================================================*/
```

Here is mine [Bootstrap](http://www.bootply.com/vjXJh9HaTx) table example.

The problem is that on `@media (max-width: 480px)` mine whole table is hiding and I only want to hide the last two `<tr class="none">....</tr>`. To be more precise I want to display four instead of seven table row on smaller screen.
SO how can I do that.

Comment: It hides last 2 rows only not whole table..

Comment: works on Chrome for me. Drops to 4 rows